# How to relate the radius of convergence with the limit of the coefficient in a power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

It's been very long since I studied this but due to COVID i've found myself having to help a younger relative with maths. Today she's presented me with a problem that I have been so far unable to answer, I've been looking through the material that she has from school and haven't been able to find an answer there either. The problem in question looks as follows:

The power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n x^n$$ converges on the interval $[-2,2)$

a. Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n$$
b. Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} nc_n$$

Now the closed interval at -2 irked me but the first thing I thought of doing was trying to find out what $c_n$ was. To do this I used the ratio test and got to a point where I know that $c_n$ needs to be something like $2^{(-n)} * a_n$ where $a_n$ is something that converges when n tends to infinity. However I've been unable to find an $a_n$ that will make the series converge on $x=-2$.

At this point I was quite bothered and thought that maybe there is a simple way to relate the interval of convergence with the limit. Can anyone shed some light into this please?

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}nc_n$?

Comment: To answer these two questions (assuming that the $x$ in the limits ought to be $n$), it is enough to know that the radius of convergence is larger than $1$. You know that $\lvert c_n\rvert \cdot \lvert x\rvert^n \to 0$ at all points of convergence. If $\lvert x\rvert > 1$, how fast does $\lvert x\rvert^n$ grow?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry the limits are when n tends to infinity of course i've edited the main question.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh that's way easier than I thought thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since $ 1\in\left[-2,2\right) $, $ \sum\limits_{n\to +\infty}{c_{n}} $ converges, thus $ c_{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 \cdot $

The power series $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 0}{n c_{n} x^{n}} $ will also have a radius of convergence $ R=2 $. Hence setting $ x=1 $, we get that$ \sum\limits_{n\geq 0}{n c_{n}} $ converges, which means $ nc_{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 \cdot $